# Sending a mail without creating a Mailable in Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5, laravel-mail

I don't see anything about sending Mail without creating a Mailable class in [Laravel 5.5 documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mail). I know it was possible before (5.2) but I don't remember how.

Is it still possible? Is it deprecated? Is there something I missed in the documentation? How can I send a mail without creating a Mailable in Laravel 5.5?

I would like something like:

```
Mail::fromText('hello world')->to('test@example.org')->send();
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I think it's not deprecated but it's assumed now that you will send more complex mails via Mailables. But it should be still possible to send mail like this:

```
\Mail::raw('hello world', function($message) {
   $message->subject('message subject')->to('test@example.org');
});
```

Comment: Will it be deprecated? I think it has to be a simple way to send emails too. Not only the complex way